# Create multidimensional array without double values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array, from sql query with several colums.
One of this is text column with names of clients.

```
$data['obchody']= $this->audytp_m->audytpro_obch();
$data['obchody_wsp']=array();
```

From this I create new array, for next step of my program:

```
$I=0;
  foreach ($data['obchody'] as $row) 
  {
    
   if(array_search($row['nieruchomosc'], array_unique(array_column($data['obchody_wsp'], 'nieruchomosc'))) ==0)   
    
     {
       $data['obchody_wsp'][$I]['nieruchomosc']=$row['nieruchomosc'];
       $data['obchody_wsp'][$I]['AudytPROInformacjaOUsludze']=$row['AudytPROInformacjaOUsludze'];
       $data['obchody_wsp'][$I]['AudytPROCzestotliwoscObchodow']=$row['AudytPROCzestotliwoscObchodow'];
     }  
     $I++; 
   }
   $I=0;
```

I use array_search to find value in new table ( column: nieruchomosc). And generally its work, but sametimes one or more  of the value is multiplify :(
I don't know why:

[image: example]

Comment: Maybe there are invisible or space characters and calling trim() the strings first would be helpful.

Comment: i try, but this same 
 [0] => Array
        (
            [nieruchomosc] => Kos Kos Zwycięstwa 202A, Koszalin
            [AudytPROInformacjaOUsludze] => 
            [AudytPROCzestotliwoscObchodow] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nieruchomosc] => Kos Kos Zwycięstwa 202A, Koszalin
            [AudytPROInformacjaOUsludze] => 
            [AudytPROCzestotliwoscObchodow] => 
        ),

Comment: hmm, this like, that only first value is multiplify

Comment: This may be happening because you have multiple clients at the same property? I don't really understand what this code is trying to achieve. How is the `$data` array used?

Comment: In one array I have many copies of client, and I create the new one, where I want to have only unique names and propertis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find the error in code.

array_search returns index of row, and "==0" is logical error, 0 is first row in array.
After var_dump i found, when array_search not find value, return's "false".

This below code working now fine:

```
if( array_search($row['nieruchomosc'], array_column($data['obchody_wsp'], 'nieruchomosc'))===false)
```